# How to prove this result? $\frac{\Gamma(1-n-a) \Gamma(1-\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(1-n) \Gamma(1 - \frac{n}{2} -a)} = 0$ if n is odd.

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

How to prove this result?

$$
\frac{\Gamma(1-n-a) \Gamma(1-\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(1-n) \Gamma(1 - \frac{n}{2} -a)} = 0\quad
\mbox{if}\ n\ \mbox{is}\ odd
$$.

My thinking is following:

We know that the poles for gamma function are $0$ and negative integers. $(1 - \frac{n}{2})$ and $(1 - \frac{n}{2} -a)$ cannot be negetive integers, so
$\Gamma(1- \frac{n}{2})$ and $\Gamma(1 - \frac{n}{2} -a)$ are analytic. So we dont have to worry about them. They dont have poles.

Now for rest of terms, both $(1-n-a)$ and $(1-n)$ are either zero or negative integers, so they are poles of gamma.

So how can I prove that this quatity is zero?

Comment: Is $a$ an arbitrary real (complex) number?

Comment: Most probably. It is not clear from the context.

Comment: If $n+a$ is a positive integer, the value is not zero for odd $n$. The statement does not hold when $n$ is a negative odd integer either.

Comment: You have to define $\displaystyle\color{red}{\tt precisely}$ the $\displaystyle a$ and $\displaystyle n$ domains.

Comment: $n$ is a natural number. About $a$, I'm not sure. Does it hold if I take $a$ as any real/complex number?